# Accessing an 'parent' namespace in c++?

Tags: c++

I've run into a piece of code in a cpp file that looks like this:

```
using namespace `A::B::C`
namespace A::B::C{  
  void function(){
    if (X::myVariable){
      //...
    }
}
```

where myVariable was defined in a different cpp file:

```
namespace A::X{
   bool myVariable = 2;
}
```

What I don't understand is why in the `void function()` under namespace `A::B::C` it was able to access `X::myVariable`.

Answer (score 2):

You are allowed to reopen a namespace, the `namespace A` is the same `A` in both places. When the compiler looks up the name `X` it looks for it in `A::B::C`, `A::B`, `A`, and the global namespace. It finds `X` in `A`.

The inner namespace has implicit access to the outer namespace. This is also allowed:

```
namespace A {
  constexpr int top = 1;
  namespace B {
    constexpr int middle = top + 1;
    namespace C {
      constexpr int bottom = middle + top;
    }
  }
}
```

[live link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/2auPLALNhL3UJPtE)

Comment: got it, but that means I must #include the header file in which namespace `A` is defined, right? Also, doesn't `using namespace A::B::C` limit the scope to only A::B::C, ie, it can't "escape" out of A::B::C to the global namespace during lookup.

Comment: @user1008636 (1)*that means I must #include the header file in which namespace A is defined, right?*  -- yes, somehow the `A::B::C` file is seeing the `A::X` file. 

(2) *doesn't using namespace A::B::C limit the scope to only A::B::C, ie, it can't "escape" out of A::B::C to the global namespace during lookup.* -- no, the using directive brings everything from that namespace into the current scope (the global scope in your case) but it does **not** mean you **only** see names from that scope. [Here's an example to help](https://wandbox.org/permlink/YAxjn3iEpftqdxNu)